# integration of PhoneGap with BlackBerry and Symbain

Tags: cordova, blackberry, symbian

I need some help on integrating phonegap for BlackBerry and Symbian OS.

I have tried with phonegap plugin for BB and Symbian but it does not work. Can somebody send me links on how it is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links,

[Getting Started with PhoneGap (BlackBerry)](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/16494777/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28BlackBerry%29)

[Getting started with PhoneGap](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-phonegap)

[Getting Started with Symbian](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_symbian_index.md.html)